# Facebook marketing api 'Unsupported get request. Object with ID '[number_of_ad_account_id]' does not exist

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm  new on Facebook marketing API.

1) they let me open only a sandbox account and I want to create a real one and get a real report.

2) after generating the example code and working with Python SDK and getting this error - 
Unsupported get request. Object with ID '[number_of_ad_account_id]' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

please help me solve this issues.
thanks.

EDIT: CODE (take from Facebook sample code)

```
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi

access_token = '{secret}'
ad_account_id = '{secret}'
app_secret = '{secret}'

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
    'account_id',
    'adgroup_id',
    'campaign_group_id',
    'campaign_id',
]
params = {
    'time_range': {'since':'2017-07-10','until':'2017-07-10'},
    'filtering': [],
    'level': 'account',
    'breakdowns': [],
}
print AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(
    fields=fields,
    params=params,
)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: sure i can do that ill edit the topic

Comment: Can you confirm that your Ad Account ID is not just a number, but also begins with `act_`

Comment: it's a number not with ad_ prefix

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. The SAMPLE_CODE.py auto-generated from Marketing API's quickstart doesn't prefix `ad_account_id` with **act_** by default; it puts the Sandbox Account ID directly, while the Ad Insights API expects:

`act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/insights`

Just prefix you `ad_account_id` with `act_` and it will work.